# rules for makefile with flags

Tags: makefile, rule

```
_OBJ = hellomake.o hellofunc.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
```

I am trying to learn makefile syntax. What is the second line saying? I am clueless. Can I get each operator what it is for in the above please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `pattern substitution` function call. Here is the [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) to the manual.

In your case, line2 prefixes all the filenames in `_OBJ` with `$(ODIR)/` and stores the results into variable `OBJ`.